# C cast funtion that takes MyType* to funtion that takes void*

Tags: c

I have something like this:

```
void vectorDestroyWithItems(Vector *vector, void (*destroyItemFunc)(void*));
void myTypeDestroy(MyType *obj);
```

and I want to call it in this way:

```
vectorDestroyWithItems(vector, myTypeDestroy);
```

But I get error:

> argument of type "void (*)(MyType *MyType)" is incompatible with parameter
> of type "void (*)(void *)

Why is it illegal?

Comment: The error message explains why.

Comment: But why compiler can't cast MyType* to void* ?

Comment: You have to do that explicitly.

Comment: So how should I call this function, without changing definition ?

Comment: Perform the cast?

Comment: OK, right thank you

Comment: Casting functions is undefined behaviour AFAIK. You have to write a wrapper function.

Comment: @user253751 Not the function, the argument.

Comment: @user253751 So is this wrong? :
`vectorDestroyWithItems(game->bases, (void (*)(void*))myTypeDestroy);`
If yes, how should I do it properly? Create another function?
I want my vector to be universal, so I don't want to change definition of it's functions.

Comment: @MateuszKisielMateuszKisiel yes, casting functions is wrong. You would have to create another function which has a `void*` parameter. I think if you compiled that, it would probably work, but in 5 years someone will try to use this vector code on a different type of computer where it doesn't work, and you'll spend a week trying to figure out why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

`void (*destroyItemFunc)(void*)`---> Function pointer, which takes `void*` as argument and do not return any value.

But ,`void myTypeDestroy(MyType *obj);`  , here the argument is of type `MyType *`,  not `void*`. This is the reason for error.

Solution : Use this
`void vectorDestroyWithItems(Vector *vector, void (*destroyItemFunc)(MyType *));`

Comment: But I don't want to change definition of vector's functions. I want to store whatever in it.